# Rotate 3D Plot in CreateDialog

Tags: dialog-window

I'm attempting to use CreateDialog to demonstrate a 3D Plot to users who are not Mathematica-ly inclined. Unfortunately, when I try to do so, using something like this piece of code:

```
            CreateDialog[ExpressionCell[Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]]]
```

the Plot can no longer be rotated, zoomed, or panned. This limits the usefulness of the Dialog, so I'd very much like to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set options in ExpressionCell:

```
CreateDialog[
 ExpressionCell[
  Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True], Selectable -> True, Deployed -> False]]
```